# TCP/IP packet data link field

Tags: tcp

It should be basic level TCP question, still unclear to me. Let's say that two PCs with static IP communicate to each other via TCP/IP and both of them are behind their routers. And let's say that local PC already has (in its cache) remote PC's MAC address (so no need for ARP). If local PC wants to send something to remote one, it puts that MAC in appropriate data link layer field (target hardware address). But then, how that packet reaches local router at the first place, when there is no it's (router's) MAC address in appropriate THA field ?

Comment: The MAC address is used in the _local network_ only: one PC will send the segment ot the MAC address of its network _router_, not to the MAC of the other PC.

Comment: Then, as packet reaches the remote router, does it (router) have to start ARP to find target computer's MAC (or it already has it in cache), because it is in router's local network ?

Comment: Precisely. Every "hop" in the route will have to do some kind of hardware to IP translation for the hop´s local network.